# JavaScript CheckBox cant get the OnCheckChange to invoke a method

Tags: c#, javascript, checkbox

So i have a checkbox and when it its checkSate is changed i want it to call a method.

heres my checkbox:

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="check2" name = "check2" Checked="True" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChangedMethod(count);">Sensor 1</input></td></tr>
```

then in my script i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnCheckedChangedMethod(count) {
        document.getElementById('mc_comboView_players').innerHTML = "<h1>" + count + "</h1>";
    }
    /*other functions*/
</script>
```

i have invoked the method via a button so i know that its works, its just not being called.

Any ideas, i think i have some wronge syntax but have not been able to figure it out.

ps i have looked else where first

Comment: The javascript event is named `change` - omit the "checked".

Comment: Yeah, OnCheckChanged is the server event to be executed when an ASP.NET checkbox control is changed. Since you're using a normal HTML input, you need to use "onclick" - "onchange" isn't supported as well as "onclick".

Comment: I was using asp:checkbox but switched to the <input>  missed the event change, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onchange` instead of `OnCheckedChanged` as OnCheckedChanged is not javascript event for checkbox change.

Also pass some `valid` value in `OnCheckedChangedMethod` as `count` might be undefined

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name = "check2" Checked="True" runat="server" onchange="OnCheckedChangedMethod(7);">
```

Comment: I think count is the reason for the problem you have as count is not defined in call  onchange="OnCheckedChangedMethod(count); change it to  onchange="OnCheckedChangedMethod(7); and tell me what it says

Comment: i tried that and again, nothing happend. Tried calling refreshLayout();  a function i added: function refreshLayout(){ document.write("<h1>REFRESHED LAYOUT</h1>");}  nothing...

Comment: Nevermind, fixed everything, had to change OnCheckedChangedMethod(count); -> OnCheckedChangedMethod("+count+");
it dynamicly fed to the browser, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Also you could use JQuery [Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event that triggered on checkbox changes. Here you can find working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/63JnE/).